# browsersync, autoreload with brunch and jade - have to reload twice before seeing changes?

Tags: javascript, pug, browser-sync, brunch

In a simple [brunch](http://brunch.io) project, I have tried using both browsersync and autoreload to keep my browser updated automatically with changes.

Edits to javascript and css are immediately updated, but when updating a jade template, the browser performs a reload, but I have to save again or manually reload the browser to see the change.

It's strange because according to the debug output, it seems to do two reloads, and also copy the html before the second reload.

**On change to jade template and save:**

```
brunch:file-list Reading 'app/index.jade' +7s
  brunch:watch File 'app/index.jade' received event 'change' +0ms
  brunch:pipeline Compiling 'app/index.jade' with 'JadeCompiler' +0ms
  brunch:pipeline getDependencies 'app/index.jade' with 'JadeCompiler' +2ms
  brunch:file-list Compiled file 'app/index.jade'... +1ms
  brunch:write Writing 1/4 files +65ms
  brunch:generate Concatenating app/index.jade, app/js/app.js to public/app.js +0ms
  brunch:common Writing file 'public/app.js' +1ms
23 Feb 16:11:04 - info: compiled index.jade and 1 cached file into app.js in 70ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
  brunch:watch File 'app/assets/index.html' received event 'change' +32ms
  brunch:file-list Copied asset 'app/assets/index.html' +1ms
  brunch:file-list Copied asset 'app/assets/index.html' +0ms
  brunch:write Writing 0/4 files +67ms
23 Feb 16:11:04 - info: copied index.html in 69ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

Comment: Brunch contrib here. Can you please create a sample application that demonstrates the issue so it's easier for us to debug? (In general, github issues should be *the* place to report bugs/unexpected behavior)

Comment: my apologies for the incredible delay @GoshaArinich - I've made an issue with a test brunch project https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1268